# Buscar y modificar en arbol binario - Java

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos, tree

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de la universidad, y necesito crear un metodo para buscar un id en un arbol y retornar el Nodo.

El nodo no solo contiene un id, si no que tiene un objeto de una clase llamada Citas con multiples campos.

Una vez que llamo al nodo.getDerecho(), o nodo.getIzquierdo, siempre me retorna null.

Alguien sabra que estoy haciendo mal?

Dejo mi codigo por si gustan echarme una mano.

Gracias

```
Clase arbol
package proyecto2;

public class Arbol {

    NodoC raiz2;


    //Citas
    
    //Agregar citas
    public void insertaCita(Citas c) {

        if (raiz2 == null) {
            raiz2 = new NodoC(c);
        } else {
            insertaRCita(raiz2, c);
        }
    }

    public void insertaRCita(NodoC n, Citas c) {
        if (n.getDato().getIdCitas() <= c.getIdCitas()) {
            if (n.getIzquierdo() == null) {
                n.setIzquierdo(new NodoC(c));
            } else {
                insertaRCita(n.getIzquierdo(), c);
            }

        } else {
            if (n.getDerecho() == null) {
                n.setDerecho(new NodoC(c));
            } else {
                insertaRCita(n.getDerecho(), c);
            }
        }
    }
  
   
    //Metodo para buscar un id en citas
    
    
   public NodoC buscarC (int id){
        NodoC temp = raiz2;
        
        while (temp.getDato().getIdCitas() != id){
            if (id < temp.getDato().getIdCitas()) {
                temp = temp.getIzquierdo();
            }else {
                temp = temp.getDerecho();
            }if (temp == null){
                return null;
            }
        }return temp;
    }
  
       
   }
   
   
    
  
  
    

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el código de la clase NodoC, si en tu contructor no eta inicializando la variables debidamente, puede ser la razon de que pierdas los datos debido a las siguiente líneas:

```
    public void insertaRCita(NodoC n, Citas c) {
        if (n.getDato().getIdCitas() <= c.getIdCitas()) {
            if (n.getIzquierdo() == null) {
                n.setIzquierdo(new NodoC(c));  <--- Cada que asignas el nodo, creas una nueva instancia.
                n.setIzquierdo(c); <-- O cambia por la siguiente instrucción
            } else {
                insertaRCita(n.getIzquierdo(), c);
            }

        } else {
            if (n.getDerecho() == null) {
                n.setDerecho(new NodoC(c)); <--- Cada que asignas el nodo, creas una nueva instancia.
                n.setDerecho(c); <-- O cambia por la siguiente instrucción
            } else {
                insertaRCita(n.getDerecho(), c);
            }
        }
    }
```